# Is is possible to reference function's parameter in the documention text?

Tags: scala, scaladoc

I woul like to reference method's parameters in the documentation text,
 but have no idea how to do it.
In .NET world we use tag [paramref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/paramref)

Just as an example:

```
/** Send email with the specified @paramref body to the addesses given in @paramref to.
@param body Just a plain text or teamplate-aware text.*/ 
def SendEmail(body: EmailBody, to: EmailAddress*) = ???
```

How is it done in Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make reference in `Scaladoc` similarly to `Javadoc`. According to [the documentation for javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javadoc.html):

```
{@code foo}
```

and

```
<code>foo</code>
```

But `XML` looks ugly and not readable, prefer to use `{@code foo}` instead.

Comment: {@code foo} just formats "foo" as code.  It's not a reference.

Comment: {@link foo} to reference foo

Answer (score -4):

I think you should find everything you need in https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/scaladoc.html. Do a string search for "param name".

Comment: This is just a style guide and not a comprehensive "how to write docs" guide.